# Sequelize- Try block won't catch on model.create() error

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, try-catch

I want to be able to reroute the website user if an error occurs in adding something to the database (a server-side validation error, like a string containing a non alphanumeric symbol or something). Currently the try-catch block doesn't catch anything even when the model.create() fails. How can I rewrite this to make it get out of the try-block and reroute back to '/' if an invalid entry is attempted?
Here's what I have (btw, Request and Ride1 are the model names):

```
/* POST request */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){

  /*a bunch of variable initializations to get form data*/

  try{
    Request.create({
      serial_num: serial_num,
      meter_reading: meter_reading,
      request_type: request_type
    })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err 
      })

    Ride1.create({
       serial_num: serial_num,
       meter_reading: meter_reading,
       request_type: request_type
     })
       .catch(err => {
         throw err 
       })

    res.redirect('/thankYou')
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log(e);
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

The .catch(err =>...) stuff doesn't seem to do anything and was just a feeble attempt at getting this to work. I think I could do it if I didn't need to Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async/await and the express-async-wrap package:

```
const wrap = require('express-async-wrap')
...
router.post('/', wrap(async function(req, res, next){
 try{
    await Request.create({
      serial_num: serial_num,
      meter_reading: meter_reading,
      request_type: request_type
    })

    await Ride1.create({
       serial_num: serial_num,
       meter_reading: meter_reading,
       request_type: request_type
     })

    res.redirect('/thankYou')
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log(e);
    res.redirect('/');
  }
}
));
```

Comment: I cannot see you using the wrap . . . can you please guide me regarding how are you using it?

Comment: I corrected my answer.